# emacs - project explorer and auto complete features - is it available?

Tags: project, emacs, software-craftsmanship

I know that Emacs is a very powerful editor out there. I try to use it occasionally and want to learn it better. But to learn it better i have to use it more frequently than I am using now.

But one big obstacle is that I could not find the basic properties like a project auto completion. Maybe I am lazy but I dont want to write again and again the same long method names. 
Another one is go to definition stuff, I want to see the real declaration of any class or method or even a variable.

Also I know that it can handle the make files but an actual representation of a project alongside the editor would be very good. 
So, what I am asking is, is there a way to provide these options in Emacs? Or is there an extended version of Emacs that supports these features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) which provides all of that sort of stuff, I should add that I havent used it myself.

I personally find [dabbrev-expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicAbbreviations) (M-/ by default) as useful, if not more, than language aware auto-completes, being able to complete in comments or from comments or code which currently won't compile is very useful.

Comment: +1 `dabbrev-expand` is the best.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclim](http://eclim.org/) is a completion package which uses Eclipse as a backend for completion and it has an emacs frontend too, so it combines the power of Eclipse's language support with the power of the Emacs interface.

Comment: it says eclipse functionality with vim editor, thanks anyway :)